# emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap for android and I am new with it. From this tutorial HelloPhoneGap http://phonegap.com/start/#android that i have followed. when I first run it it runs ok, but later-on when I run it i got this error. I am sure my code is correct because i followed the tutorial step-by-step.

```
emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

I have searched on the internet on how to solve this case but I found no one.

i think the problem is in the SDK but i have also tried to un-install an reinstall but i have failed.

if it is possible, can it be done by not un-install an re-install anything?

can anyone have an idea about my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But what do you want to correct? It's a common warning for emulators. In case of emulator there are no actual sensors that's why it unable to create sensor port. Moreover, this warning appears during the boot of the emulator. If you stop it after this message it is not right. You should wait more until emulator boot.